# Issue while loading image in ImageView

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I am developing an app that uses wifi to transfer the screen image of desktop to android device.I am able to transfer the image as byte array from PC to Android device.But unable to view the image in ImageView component at android device.Following are two pieces of code from server(PC) and client(Android Device):

**Server**:

```
DataOutputStream ds=new DataOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
Rectangle rect= new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
Robot rb=new Robot();
img=rb.createScreenCapture(rect);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(img, "PNG",baos);
byte[] image=baos.toByteArray();
baos.flush();
baos.close();
System.out.println(image.length);
ds.writeInt(image.length);
ds.write(image);
ds.flush();
ds.close();
```

**Client**:

```
DataInputStream bis=new DataInputStream(csoc.getInputStream());
int imgsize=bis.readInt();
byte[] img=new byte[imgsize];
int m;
while((m=bis.read())!=-1){
bis.read(img,0,img.length);
}
bis.close();
BitmapFactory.Options op=new BitmapFactory.Options();
op.inSampleSize=8;
Bitmap bmpim=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img,0,img.length);
imv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img,0,img.length,op));//imv is ImageView object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this, considering your inputstream is valid

```
DataInputStream bis=new DataInputStream(csoc.getInputStream());
    imageView=new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis));
// Add this imageView to existing parent layout
// parentLayout.addView(imageView);
```

Comment: Thanks.By changing the code as above,I will need to add ImageView on the layout manually?Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I tried using the above code but still not getting the image in ImageView.Is it necessary to use findViewById with the above given code?I tried both with n without but to no avail.Is it that there is some image resolution problem between the devices?Because my PC screen resolution is set to 1280*800 and that of my Android device is 480*800.

Comment: Using this code you need to add the imageview to layout container existing on page

Comment: I am still not able to get things right.Any suggestions for alternate methods?

Comment: Kindly help.I am still not able to view the image in ImageView.Till now I have tried following ways: 1) Using **Bitmap.createScaledBitmap**,**Bitmap.compress**,**manually creating ImageView**.But nothing works.The image just doesn't show up in the ImageView.Whereas it shows up in the application I am running on PC.Should I first save the image on android media and then try to retrieve it by doing decodeFile?

Comment: Yes you can try doing that

Comment: As mentioned earlier tried to store the file in sdcard.it gets stored as 'png'. fair enough.but when I try to open it through my Gallery it gives one 'big yellow exclamation' mark.the image is 1280*800 res.also,the same res image which I manually copied from my PC into the sdcard of android device is getting opened through Gallery.BTW I am iserting the image in sdcard using the following code:`MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());`

Comment: Hi I am able to get through with this problem.Apparently my byte array on receiver's end was not getting  wasn't getting properly built in earlier version of code.I solved it by using ArrayList as follows:`while((m=bis.read())!=-1)
  {
      imlist.add(m);
  }
  byte[] imbyte=new byte[imlist.size()];
  for(int c=0;c<imlist.size();c++)
  {
      imbyte[c]=imlist.get(c).byteValue();}`..Thanks a lot everyone for all the assistance.